# why do I get a ValidationError when using put_metric_alarm in AWS boto3?

Tags: boto3

I'm trying to create an alarm using this code

```
import boto3 as b3
session = b3.Session(profile_name = 'MyAccount')
cw = session.client('cloudwatch', region_name = 'us-east-1')
response = cw.put_metric_alarm(AlarmName = 'corefactoring-dev-bnvhf-apps_i-0840f49234febb756_disk_used_percent_rootfs',
                            ActionsEnabled= True,
                            AlarmActions= ['arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:354701104343:TopicCloudWatch-TopicForAlarms-WSVUK43NQYMP'],
                            OKActions= ['arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:354701104343:TopicCloudWatch-TopicForAlarms-WSVUK43NQYMP'],
                            InsufficientDataActions= ['notBreaching'],
                            MetricName= 'disk_used_percent',
                            Namespace= 'CWAgent',
                            Statistic='Average',
                            Dimensions=[{'Name': 'path', 'Value': '/'}, {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': 'i-0840f49234febb756'}, {'Name': 'device', 'Value': 'rootfs'}, {'Name': 'fstype', 'Value': 'rootfs'}],
                            Period= 60,
                            EvaluationPeriods= 3,
                            ComparisonOperator = 'GreaterThanThreshold',
                            Threshold= 80.0
                            )
print(response)
```

And I'm getting this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "disk_alarms.py", line 49, in 
    Threshold= 80.0
  File "/opt/venvs/awscli/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/venvs/awscli/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: Unknown

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: InsufficientDataActions expects a list of ARNs. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_alarm. notBreaching is a value for TreatMissingData.

Comment: I noticed that and I'm sending a single value list: ['notBreaching']

Comment: But the list for InsufficientDataActions needs to be valid ARNs.

Comment: That is so true I changed InsuficientDataAction to TreatMissingData and now I got a working code